# Is it possible to conditionally implement the comma ok idiom in go, like map lookup?

Tags: go, overloading, multiple-return-values

In golang, you can fetch a key from a map using the obvious syntax:

```golang
someMap := map[string]string{
   //... contents
}

value := someMap["key1"]
// If "key1" exists in someMap, then the value will be returned; else empty string.
```

Problem: You can't tell missing keys apart from legitimate empty string values

So, you can test for presence using the comma ok idiom

```golang
value, ok := someMap["key1"]
if ok {
   // we know that "key1" was in the map, even if value is empty string
} else {
   // we know that "key1" was NOT in the map
}
```

What this *looks like* is that there are two different overloads of the map lookup method, one which returns just a single map `value` result, and one which returns the `(value, bool)` result, and the compiler seems to be selecting the overload based on how many return values you've said you'd like to receive.

This is quite nice, and I was wondering if it was possible to implement this on my own functions?

E.g:

```golang
func fetchValue() (string, bool) {
    return "", true
}

func testMain() {
    // This works fine, as expected
    val, ok := fetchValue()
    if ok {
        fmt.Println(val)
    }

    // COMPILE ERROR: Assignment count mismatch: 1 = 2.
    val2 := fetchValue()
}

// COMPILE ERROR: fetchValue redeclared in this package
func fetchValue() string {
    return ""
}
```

Is this possible? or is it secret special language sauce that only works for the builtin `map` type and nothing else?

Comment: In short: the special syntax with maps and channels are backed by the language spec, you can't create functions that may be used the same.

Comment: There are a few places in the specs where you can see this "two possible assignments" feature, like getting a value from a map (your question), iterating over an array or a map, dynamically casting an interface to a concrete type. In that last case, the difference is even more blatant : the 1-value assignment may panic, while the 2-values assignment never panics. These are all built-in features and can't be implemented with your own code.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot define your own function that sometimes returns 2 values, sometimes 1.

You can do:

```golang
val, ok := fetchValue()
if !ok {
    // failure path.
}
```

or

```golang
val, _ := fetchValue()
// not checking for failure.
```